# How add a Google Analytics Event to all all <audio> tags, with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, audio, google-analytics

I need to add a Google Analytics Event to all audio tags.

I can do it if all the audio tags belong to a specific class:

```
<script>
/* a test script */
$(function() {
  // Every button with the audioClass class can execute the function.
  $( "audioClass" ).on("click", (function() {
    ga('send', 'event', 'audioclass', 'clicked', 'test');
    });
  });
</script>
```

But can it be done just using the audio tag (i.e. without the classname)?

```
<script>
/* 2nd test script */
$(function() {
  // Every audio tag will hopefully execute the function.
  $("audio").on("click", function() {
    ga("send", "event", "audio", "clicked", "test");
    });
  });
</script>
```

I found a similar answer here: [Adding play buttons for all audio tags on a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37896698/adding-play-buttons-for-all-audio-tags-on-a-page)
But I can't see how to use its:

> $( "audio" ).each(function( index ) {

In my code.

Answer (score 0):

You are propably looking for the onplay event:

```js
    $("audio").on("play", function() {
       ga("send", "event", "audio", "clicked", "test");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio controls>
  <source src="http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/280.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
```